# Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided. (With Express as framework)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I saw a lot of questions with the same title and they did help me to some extent but I never actually got rid of this error that I was having.

For your background information, I created a file called listing.js as a platform to run node command. 
I was trying to use node.js via **listing.js** to serve a webpage called **weatha-picka.html** along with its external components consisting of **weatha-picka.js** and **weatha-picka.css.**

Here is the folder tree in which the 3 files above were mentioned above: 
[image: Click here to see the picture.]

Below is what I have written in **listing.js** to start up the server :

```js
// Module dependencies 
var application_root = __dirname,
path = require( 'path' ); 
express = require( 'express' ); 

// Creating server // 
var app = express();  

// Configurating the server   
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', {});
});  
app.use( express.static( path.join( application_root, 'site')));  

// Starting the server 
app.listen(3500, () => {console.log("hold my Mac")});
```

Even though I had previously tried middlewares like `body-parser`, the error message nonetheless is still the same on `localhost:3500`.

> Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
>       at new View (/Users/quanvihong/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:61:11)
>       at Function.render (/Users/quanvihong/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:570:12)
>       at ServerResponse.render (/Users/quanvihong/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1012:7)
>       at /Users/quanvihong/Desktop/Weathers/server/listing.js:11:7
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/quanvihong/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (/Users/quanvihong/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (/Users/quanvihong/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/quanvihong/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>       at /Users/quanvihong/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
>       at Function.process_params (/Users/quanvihong/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)

All in all, the burning question is whether the error comes from over simplicity in `listing.js` or the file hierarchy ?
I was quite new to nodejs so any suggestions and recommendations would be highly appreciated.

Comment: did you set the view engine `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');`

Comment: Nope. What was app.set() by the way?

Comment: it's an express method to set variables, in your case, you need to set a default view engine so try this code ` app.set('view engine', 'jade');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any `index` view for server rendering. Try to create a `index.html` as your home page and correct it in `listing.js`.

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

If you want to serve `weatha-picka.html` as a static page, just return it like:

```js
app.get('/weatha-picka', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/weatha-picka.html');
});
```

---

Additionally, in case of you want to create more view as `weatha-picka`, try to use [ejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs) template module. Below are samples of ejs and express.

In `listing.js`:

```
const express = require('express');

var app = express(); 

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, './public')); // ejs engine looks for ejs files in public folder

app.get('/weatha-picka', function (req, res) {
  res.render('weatha-picka', {});
});
```

In `/public` folder, create `weatha-picka.ejs` template file:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>EJS template</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Use ejs template and html here -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `node_modules` uses to contains module from nodejs, it should not be a source folder of project and even I just see `node_packages` not `node_modules`???

Comment: I was also curious what sendFile actually means.

Comment: Express `sendFile()` method can be used to send static files to the client, it means server will render page from static html file. I recommend you use ejs for dynamically rendering with data (not as a static html)

Comment: About this LOC ``` app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, './public')); ``` , does it create "public" folder or do I have to create this myself in advance ?

Comment: You need to create `public` in advance, `public` folder will contains any public resources such as html, css, js, images...

Comment: What do you mean by creating more view as weatha-picka?  Is it that I can include more links to the website itself or adding styles ?

Comment: It mean some another pages (links)